# JSF 2.2: PhaseListener shall only run before first request of a session

Tags: session, jsf-2.2, phaselistener

I'm working on a PhaseListener which runs before RESTORE_VIEW and I need to know whether it runs for the first time in the current session or not (so that I can do some auto-login for stay-logged-in-users).

Any hints for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do such a thing. I have a same phase listener:

```
@Override
public PhaseId getPhaseId() {
    return PhaseId.RESTORE_VIEW;
}

@Override
public void beforePhase(PhaseEvent event) {
    FacesContext ctx = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    if (!ctx.isPostback()) {
    authRet = // check for active session
    if (!authRet) {
         if (...)// check for cookies { //create auth}
         else { // redirect to login }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm creating an infinite loop in the moment: !postback leeds to redirect which is again !postback what leeds to redirect what is again !postback ...
So how do you get authRet? Like checking if there's a valid user in the session?

Comment: Ok, thats it. My condition now looks like if (!ctx.potsback() && loginController != null && loginController.getCurrentUser() != null) ...

Comment: I usually check if the request url is the login url for this kind of issue. If the answer worked for you, please accept it as right answer. Thank you!